# matlab: efficient search a value within the array

Tags: arrays, performance, matlab, search, find

I have an array of already ordered values (e.g. vec=[20, 54, 87, 233]). Array contains ~300 elements. I have a value, which I need to search in this array. The successful search is not only the exact value, but also +/- 5 digits within the range. For example, in this case values like 17 or 55 should be also considered as found. What is the most efficient way to do this? I used the loop like below, but I guess it does not take in the account that my array is already ordered. In addition, in case of non-empty I get to check manually how distant was the value because find does not return position. This is not a big problem since my "finds" are only 15%.

```
bRes  = find(vec >= Value-5 & vec <= Value+5);
if ~isempty(bRes)
    distGap = GetGapDetails(Value, vec);
    return;
end
```

Thanks!
Vadim

Comment: just use `hist` or `histc`

Comment: But how it will help me? The hist bins values for fixed ranges (1-10,11-20 etc). My query value might belong to different bin.

Comment: @user1597969 You can define custom bin edges with `hist`. Non-uniform is fine.

Answer (score 1):

The best way to search for a value in a list that is already sorted is a [binary search](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search), which takes only `O(log(n))` time. This is better than comparing the value with every item in the list, which costs `O(n)`. As far as I know, Matlab does not have a function to do exactly this. As already mentioned by Natan, you can (a)buse the built-in function [histc](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/histc.html) for this, which is written in C and presumably does a binary search.

```
function good = is_within_range(value, vector, threshold)

% check that vector is sorted, comment this out for speed
assert(all(diff(vector) > 0))
assert(threshold > 0)

% pad vector with +- inf for histc
vector = [-inf, vector, inf];

% find index of value in vector, so that vector(ind) <= value < vector(ind+1)
% abuse histc, ignore bincounts
[~, ind] = histc(value, vector);

% check if we are within +- threshold from a value in vector,
% either below or above
good = (value <= vector(ind) + threshold) | value >= (vector(ind+1) - threshold);
```

Some quick tests:

```
>> is_within_range(0, [10, 30, 80], 5)
ans = 0
>> is_within_range(4, [10, 30, 80], 5)
ans = 0
>> is_within_range(5, [10, 30, 80], 5)
ans = 1
>> is_within_range(10, [10, 30, 80], 5)
ans = 1
>> is_within_range(15, [10, 30, 80], 5)
ans = 1
>> is_within_range(16, [10, 30, 80], 5)
ans = 0
>> is_within_range(31, [10, 30, 80], 5)
ans = 1
>> is_within_range(36, [10, 30, 80], 5)
ans = 0
```

And as a bonus, this function is vectorized, so you can test more than one value at the same time:

```
>> is_within_range([0, 4, 5, 10, 15, 16, 31, 36], [10, 30, 80], 5)
ans =
     0     0     1     1     1     0     1     0
```

Answer (score 0):

This will be somewhat more efficient:

```
bRes  = vec >= Value-5 & vec <= Value+5;
if any(bRes) ...
```

You are right that MATLAB will likely not take advantage of the fact that 'vec' is already sorted.  You could write a binary search to zero in on the range of interest (that is, work in O(log(N)) time rather than O(N) time), but with only 300 elements in the array, I suspect your current implementation will hold up well.

Comment: Thanks!
In fact my find was 15% faster than what you prosed :)

Answer (score -1):

let's say your array is stored in var 'A' and your value is 'v':

```
A(A>v+5 || A<v-5)=[];
```